# sending data from PIC to laptop via bluetooth

Tags: windows, bluetooth, pic

I am working on a school project where I will use a PIC to transmit simple integers via bluetooth to be displayed on my laptop. I am unsure where to start looking when it comes to writing a program that can receive this bluetooth data and convert to a message to be displayed. Can anyone point my in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `HC-05 Serial Port Bluetooth Module`.

[image]

You can find a lot of tutorials like [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Cheap-2-Way-Bluetooth-Connection-Between-Arduino-a/) explaining how to deal with them.